# Creating an infinite for loop

Tags: python, loops

I wanted to test if python would let me run this code:

```
listWords = []
for i in range (len(listWords)+1):
    listWords.append("New word")
print ("End loop")
```

The reason being I want to create a programme that tries to solve a solution and then adds new items to a list for testing.

Why does python NOT update the for loop range when I add a new item to the list?

Is there any way around this using a for loop? (I suspect a while loop will do for my case, but I am just curious)

Thanks

Comment: The iterator expression for the for-loop is evaluated before it runs. You can use a while loop instead.

Comment: `range(len(…))` is never going to be best practice Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, updating a list while iterating it is generally *a bad idea*. However, it seems like in this case this is exactly what you want to do. Instead of calculating the `len` of the list *before* iterating the list (which is exactly why it is never updated) you could iterate the elements in the list directly.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> for x in lst:
...     if x < 10:
...         lst.append(x*2)
...         
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 8, 12, 8, 16, 16]
```

If you need the index of the current element (or both the index and the element itself) you could use `for i, x in enumerate(lst)` to the same effect.

Comment: fab. thanks :) just an interesting alternative to the while loop. 
I'm a new programmer so am interested in ideas!!

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over a list which you are simultaneously updating is bad practice.

In your code, the range is already calculated before you run the loop, so the range will be `range(1)`, and then the for loop runs just that once and stops. This can also be observed if `listWords` is not empty, but is `listWords = ['a','b']`, so below loop run 3 times since the iterator is `range(3)`

Then the code becomes.

```
listWords = ['a','b']
for i in range (len(listWords)+1):
    listWords.append("New word")
print ("End loop")
print(listWords)
['a', 'b', 'New word', 'New word', 'New word']
```

While loop doesn't have such a limitation, The below example will keep running since len(listWords) is always updated at the end of next iteration

```
listWords = []
i = 0
while i <  (len(listWords)+1):
    listWords.append("New word")
    i+=1
```

Comment: Fixed it! Please take a look @meowgoesthedog